# When adding sparklines in Excel 2013 via VBA, source data worksheet references are inconsistent

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code which is run for each cell in a range:

```
Set sparklineRng = range(Cells(currentRow, startCol), Cells(currentRow, endCol))

Cells(currentRow, valueCol).SparklineGroups.Add Type:=xlSparkLine, SourceData:=sparklineRng.Address
```

The sparkline is supposed to be using the data range on the same worksheet that it is drawn on, but the problem is that some of the cells (not all), are referencing another worksheet.

When I go to Edit Data for a cell, I get either of these as my data reference:

```
$M$7:$X$7
```

OR

```
'Raw Data'!$M$7:$X$7
```

$M$7:$X$7 is the correct reference, not the one referencing the "Raw Data" tab.

Each time I run the macro I get different results.  Any idea what is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fully qualify each Range and Cell object with a worksheet.
i.e.

```
with wsYourWorksheet
    Set sparklineRng = .range(.cells(currentrow, startCol),.cells(currentrow, endCol))
end with
```

Comment: Thanks!  I actually used a slightly different method to get this to work, which was to append the sheet name to the address string: SourceData:="'" & currentSheet & "'!" & sparklineRng.Address

Comment: No worries thanks for tick :) Where you say currentsheet, do you mean activesheet? It's good that worked but i'd still recommend using the actual worksheet object as "best practise", then you don't have to make sure you activate the sheet or anything... You'll notice that all sheets are objects by default, i.e. "Sheet 1" is normally sheet1 etc... so you can use as above or the long way sheet1.range(sheet1.cells(..), sheet1.cells(...)) without having to set a new object